# Using usb to connect Android to Pixhawk

Tags: dronekit, dronekit-android

I am looking for a way to connect my pixhawk to an android device using the USB(OTG) cable.

After doing some research i figured there is two possible ways to do that. Either using the micro usb port on the pixhawk or just using a USB FTDI cable to use the telemetry port.

What i am asking if it would be possible to use dronekit android with either of those options ?

If yes which one would you recommend.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I consider you wanna make a "flying Android"? 
Android device is not a good onboard device because of its poor IO ports.But Android is a good device to be a ground station.

You can only use a USB FTDI to connect each other.The micro-usb on pixhawk is used to debug,your vehicle while not fly if pixhawk's micro-usb is in use.